# How to disable SSLv2 in OpenSSH?

Tags: ssh, openssl

Due to the recent deprecation of SSLv2, is it possible to disable SSLv2 in OpenSSH?

Is OpenSSH even using SSLv2?

From digging around, I see the sshd is not compiled against openssl , but it is compiled against libcrypto (which is part of the openssl package).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSH and SSL are entirely different protocols.  OpenSSH doesn't have anything to do with SSL, so you don't have to worry about it.  The reason sshd is linked against libcrypto is that libcrypto implements a lot of cryptography-related functions, and OpenSSH uses that code instead of duplicating it.

Comment: I wouldn't say OpenSSH has nothing to do with SSL: 1) openssl certificates usually also use RSA keys (which you can in fact use with openssh) and 2) an invalid openssl.cnf may block ssh access. I managed that. For testing purposes only. Erm...